# Can I reenter the US on ESTA after my J-1 has expired?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I am Danish university student currently studying in CA for a year on a J-1 visa.

Some of my old friends from Denmark would come to the US during the last week of my grace period. I want to do a road trip with them for about three weeks to see CA but then I would need another visa.

I planned to go to Belize/Nicaragua for about a week (as I'm a scuba diver) during my grace period and come back on the ESTA.

I'm worried about whether I will be allowed reentry at this point. I plan to keep ownership/registration of my car (and phone plan + bank account) so that I/we can use it on our road trip.

Should I be worried about being denied reentry?

Answer (score 1):

Noone will be able to give you a definite answer but make sure you can show hotel reservation and plane tickets going home at the border. Explaining the truth can't hurt either.